# Divs overlap and ellipsis not working in fluid layout

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a fluid layout with 2 divs (named status and status_edit) in a container.
The second div is overlapping when resizing the window, also ellipsis are not working on the `status_list` spans. Do you have any solution? i have tried a lot.

[You can see it in this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyas/9cFU4/2/)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `li` inside `.status-edit` are floating outside the box. You could add `overflow: auto` to `.status-edit`. However, when the screensize gets smaller, 'icon1' and 'icon2' disappear. To fix that, you could set a min-width to `.status-edit`.

You could also set a min-widht to `.container`. The div than will be resized in ratio, depending on the window size but will keep a defined minimum width. When the window size gets smaller than that value, the horizontal scrollbar will appear.

Comment: Thanks, when i add the min-width for the .status-edit and resize the browser, the icons are moving down

Comment: i think when we set min-width:500px for .container, the icons are not stepping down, if it goes below then the width,  overlapping  is happenning

Comment: Then increase the min-widht, to like 600px or 800px

Comment: i could not, because its a fluid layout for all the screen resolution and mobile devices, i would like to find a way to achieve this, also why this ellipsis not working?

Comment: Then set a minimum width to both `.status-list` and `.status-edit`. Then when the window reaches that size, both will be display underneath each other.

Comment: Thanks, i have fixed the issue with width:calc CSS